# Multithreading code is getting executed twice through Robot file

Tags: python, robotframework

I am running a python multithreaded code which runs only once if i run it through python file but runs twice if i run it through Robot file :

python file code :

```
def connect():
        print("Step 12: Reload devices")
        config_threads_list = []
        ipAddress = '172.22.12.14'
        username = 'abcd'
        password = 'abcd'
        devices = ['5023','5024','5025','5026']
        for ports in devices:
            consoleServer, username, password, port = ipAddress, username, password, ports
            print ('Creating thread for: ', ports)
            config_threads_list.append(threading.Thread(target=obj.router_reload, args=(consoleServer, username, password, port)))
    
        print ('\n---- Begin get config threading ----\n')
        for config_thread in config_threads_list:
            config_thread.start()
    
        for config_thread in config_threads_list:
            config_thread.join()

connect()
```

this code works fine when i run it through python only . However when i run it through robot framework its running twice

robot file :

```
Documentation        Test case
Library             <path to above py file >

*** Test Cases ***
TEST CASE LEL-TC-1
    connect
```

Comment: I havent used this framework but im guessing you could use `if __name__ == "__main__": connect()` to fix it

Comment: man ,please post this comment as an answer and i will give you upvote and green tick mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to share why it is executed twice when you run the robot file.

You call `connect()` at the end of the Python file. This is the single invocation when the Python script is executed.

Now when you import the Python file as a library its actually gets executed. So the `connect()` will be called at the end. That is one.

Then you call it explicitly as a keyword in the test case. That is two.

To avoid this simply remove the `connect()` call from the end of the Python file.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180176/joshua-nixon](http://joshua%20nixon)

after using the below mentioned simple/basic yet very effective code my issue has been resolved from robot file as well and code is only getting executed once :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   connect()
```